# How do you program a device driver for OSX?

Tags: macos, assembly, drivers

So I am trying to make a hackintosh, and I want to write a device driver for a piece of hardware I have.

How would one go about learning how to program device drivers? Does it require assembly language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to write a Kernel extension.

Apple has a introduction to the topic [in their developer library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIntro/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn I/O Kit--it's the (embedded) C++ framework/runtime in the kernel. What kind of device is it? PCI?

Here's another documentation link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Intro/AH_Intro.html

Good luck...